# Angular material progress bar lining up with two values

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to line up on a single line a value, a material progress bar and another value.

I have implemented a Material progress bar and the values using the following code:

```css
.progress-bar-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.lower-limit {
  float: left;
}

.higher-limit {
  float: right;
}

.progress-bar {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<mat-card-content>
  <div id="textbox">
    <p class="alignleft">My Description</p>
    <p class="alignright">20</p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <div class=progress-bar-container>
    <div class=lower-limit>0</div>
    <div class=progress-bar>
      <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="50" bufferValue="100"></mat-progress-bar>
    </div>
    <div class=higher-limit>40</div>
  </div>

</mat-card-content>
```

This is the resultant display:

[image: picture of incorrect line up]

I am trying to show the scale so each number needs to be at either end of the bar.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` on your `progress-bar-container` to get the 3 divs to fit within it.

Try this in your css

```css
.progress-bar-container {
    display: flex;
}

.lower-limit {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.higher-limit {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-progress-range).